# How do you define a Experience Handler for Microsoft Tag in Android?

Tags: android, camera, microsoft-tag

I've been asked by a client to include Microsoft Tag support in an Android app we are creating for them.
I've downloaded the SDK and managed to include the MS Tag Android jar into my project.
I built the demo projects, and have tag scanning working in our app. 
I've defined a tag (of the free text type) using the online interface ([this](http://tag.microsoft.com/manageads.aspx)) and scanned it using the app.
 
But the payload returned is null.
The tag works fine when using micosofts Tag app, displaying the text.
all I want to do is get the text for the tag, and have my app handel it.
according to [this](http://tag.microsoft.com/developer/sdk-application-requirements.aspx):
What I want is a 'Custom Experiance', probably by using an 'Experience Handler'.
 
However, there is no hint in the supplied code or online doumentation (that I can find) as to how this is achived.
any help would be greatly appericated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your post to add some paragraph breaks to make it somewhat readable. Just as a point of info, you can preview your post real-time as you enter it (and before you submit it) immediately below the `Submit answer` button. It will actually update as you type your question, so you can see how it will appear before posting. The Enter key works perfectly well in most browsers for inserting paragraph breaks, and if it doesn't you can use the standard HTML &lt;br /&gt; and &lt;p&gt; markup. The easier it is to read your question, the faster you can get answers. :)

Comment: Thanks Ken, yeah I'm new at this :)

Comment: No problem. :) Everyone is at some point. <g>

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I haven't exactly figured it out, but I did get an email from the Tag Support Team
It looks something like this:

> Thank you for reaching out to Tag Support.
>   
>   Please know  that the associated text can be associated with *any* Tag (not just free text).
>   
>   You need to use the Tag creation API to create a Tag and add the payload.
>   Once logged in to your LiveID account, you should be able to go to the Key Manager page and download the Tag Custom Payload Creation project.
>   This project (which you can simply use, once loaded in VS 2010 and built) shows how to create such a payload and attach to a Tag.
>   
>   If you have any questions, comments or suggestions, please let us know.
>   
>   Thank you for your feedback and your interest in Microsoft Tag.
>   
>   Best Regards,
>   
>   Microsoft Tag Support Team

Since I'm being provided with tags that have allready been created by the cilent, I don't need to tak this step, but I hope it helps anyone else strugging with this problem.